# Call previous ancestors explicitely

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Text`, to which I prepend different modules such as `Capitalize` or `Trim`. At the end, I get:

```
Text.ancestors # => [Capitalize,Trim,Text,Object,Kernel]
```

I want to call a method that corrects a text. By calling a method that returns a text with the behaviour of the previous ancestor, I want to recursively go through each ancestor until I reach `Text` class, and return the text.

I have a problem. Each module and class has the same method named `correct_text`, and I can't create any alias. When I pass through `Capitalize`, it has no problem, but when I recursively call a method in `Trim`, I cannot call the method on this ancestor (private method or by using `send`) since there is a method with the same name on `Capitalize`, which ends up being called according to the order.

Is it possible to call a method on an ancestor? Is it possible to undo a `prepend`/`include`/`extend` without using `undef_method`?

Comment: Just call `super` in your prepended methods.

Comment: Is this not going to call Text each time ?

Comment: nope, it's not.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all, but my guess is that you are misunderstanding the term "recursive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `super` in your prepended methods.

```
module Capitalize
  def correct_text
    super.capitalize
  end
end

module Trim
  def correct_text
    super.strip
  end
end

class Text
  prepend Capitalize
  prepend Trim

  def correct_text
    'hello '
  end
end

Text.new.correct_text # => "Hello"
```

Comment: And if i can't modify any module ?  
Capitalize call just the recursive method and after that get the text modified by previous modules (if some exists) and after that capitalize the text and returns it, with no super

Comment: @B.DC: what do you mean "can't modify"? 1) you can. 2) where did you imagine to put this code that will traverse the ancestors and call their implementations?

Comment: @B.DC: If your modules don't handle `super`, then they're not  prepend-friendly, and you may have to choose some other way of building your processing pipeline.

Comment: @B.DC I am still not sure I really understand the question here but you could hack together the functionality without `super` (which as pointed out is the only way to make prepend friendly modules). Here is a very [awkward example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/IgnorantVirtualScreencast) based on my limited understanding of your situation